# Dimension change of convolutional layer after applying the feature map

Tags: cnn, feature-map

In this [lecture](https://youtu.be/bNb2fEVKeEo?t=1259) I don't understand how the output has 1 layer after applying the feature map to the 3 layer input.

Comment: is the feature map the  5*5*3 filter?  If so applying a 3 layer filter to a 3 layer input would produce a 1 layer output wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is. my question is why it would turn to be 1 from 3

Comment: she says, "center the filter on each pixel and perform a dot product which gives one value per position.  So I'm guessing it is a dot product between (L1, L2, L3)  dot (F1, F2, F3) where L's are pixel values in the input and F's are whatever values are in the filter I think.

Comment: Yes that makes sense now. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the video the speaker says, "center the filter on each pixel and perform a dot product which gives one value per position." 
So I'm guessing it is a dot product between (L1, L2, L3) dot (F1, F2, F3) where L's are pixel values in the input and F's are whatever values are in the filter.